# How to read inline-styles from WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to put text into a RichTextCtrl and then, after the user has made edits, I want to get the edited text back out along with the styles. Its the second part I'm having trouble with. Out of all the methods to get styles out of the buffer, none of them are really user-friendly.

The best I've come up with is to walk through the text a character at a time with `GetStyleForRange(range, style)`. There has *got* to be a better way to do this! Here's my code now, which walks through gathering a list of text segments and styles.

Please give me a better way to do this. I have to be missing something.

```py
        buffer: wx.richtext.RichTextBuffer = self.rtc.GetBuffer()
        end = len(buffer.GetText())

        # Variables for text/style reading loop
        ch: str
        curStyle: str
        i: int = 0
        style = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
        text: List[str] = []
        textItems: List[Tuple[str, str]] = []

        # Read the style of the first character
        self.rtc.GetStyleForRange(wx.richtext.RichTextRange(i, i + 1), style)
        curStyle = self.describeStyle(style)

        # Loop until we hit the end. Use a while loop so we can control the index increment.
        while i < end + 1:
            # Read the current character and its style as `ch` and `newStyle`
            ch = buffer.GetTextForRange(wx.richtext.RichTextRange(i, i))
            self.rtc.GetStyleForRange(wx.richtext.RichTextRange(i, i + 1), style)
            newStyle = self.describeStyle(style)

            # If the style has changed, we flush the collected text and start new collection
            if text and newStyle != curStyle and ch != '\n':
                newText = "".join(text)
                textItems.append((newText, curStyle))
                text = []
                self.rtc.GetStyleForRange(wx.richtext.RichTextRange(i + 1, i + 2), style)
                curStyle = self.describeStyle(style)

            # Otherwise, collect the character and continue
            else:
                i += 1
                text.append(ch)

        # Capture the last text being collected
        newText = "".join(text)
        textItems.append((newText, newStyle))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in python, but in C++ you can call GetBuffer() to get the document buffer, then call GetChildren() on the buffer to get a list of the first level document nodes.  Then start walking the document's tree.  For each object you find, you can call GetRange() to see where it came from and GetProperties() to get the styles associated with that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a C++ version of the solution I mentioned in the comment above.  It's a simple tree walk using a queue, so I think should be translatable to python easily.

```
const wxRichTextBuffer& buffer = m_richText1->GetBuffer();
std::deque<const wxRichTextObject*> objects;
objects.push_front(&buffer);

while ( !objects.empty() )
{
    const wxRichTextObject* curObject = objects.front();
    objects.pop_front();

    if ( !curObject->IsComposite() )
    {
        wxRichTextRange range = curObject->GetRange();
        const wxRichTextAttr& attr = curObject->GetAttributes();

        // Do something with range and attr here.
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a composite object. Add its children to the queue.
        // The children are added in reverse order to do a depth first walk.
        const wxRichTextCompositeObject* curComposite =
            static_cast<const wxRichTextCompositeObject*>(curObject);

        size_t childCount = curComposite->GetChildCount() ;

        for ( int i = childCount - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
        {
            objects.push_front(curComposite->GetChild(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize there was an underlying tree, but that makes so much more sense. This is a huge help, thank you.